# Sending data to a new view controller through didselectrowatindexpath

Tags: swift

I have a tableview set up in one view controller and I am trying to send the indexPath.row text to a new view controller's label. I am getting an error that says it found nil when unwrapping an optional value. If I print "selectedClass" in the viewController code shown below, I get the text of indexPath.row. If I print the text in the new viewController, I get nothing. Here is my code:

---

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

```
    let classIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(classIndexPath)! as UITableViewCell


    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.labelText = "Just a Moment"

    if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {

        spinningActivity.hide(true)

        self.displayAlert("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing.")


    } else {

        spinningActivity.hide(true)

        let selectedClass = selectedCell.textLabel!.text!

        let newCardSetVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewCardSetViewController") as! NewCardSetViewController

        newCardSetVC.selectedClassLabel.text = selectedClass as String



        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addCardSetSegue", sender: self)


    }

}
```

---

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `NewCardSetViewController` and using a `segue` together. Is that really what you want?

Comment: What Eendje said. you are not using the newCardSetVC instance you created?

Comment: `self.presentViewController(newCardSetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: you could also call `performSegueWithIdentifier` and then in `prepareForSegue` do all the logic of passing the selectedClass value to the VC

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this, where you create a new instance of `NewCardSetVC` , and also use a `segue`. That could be why your having this issue. Try using a `prepareForSegue` method to pass along the text info you need

Comment: Thanks everyone! I needed to change performSegueWithIdentifier to presentViewController and set selectedClass = selectedClass in the new VC rather than the label. In the new VC, I set selected class = selectedClassLabel.

Comment: Have a look at SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386919/10661965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set string value in label of `NewCardSetViewController`.

`NewCardSetViewController` will only load in memory after perform segue.
So, viewDidLoad() of `NewCardSetViewController` will call after segue.

In your code you are trying to set value before segue perform.
To passData in nextViewController you need to create variable with same dataType of data your are trying to pass.

In your case create string variable in `NewCardSetViewController` say `strSelectedClass`, instead of setting value directly to label, set value of that variable i.e. `strSelectedClass`.

**Replace line**

```
newCardSetVC.selectedClassLabel.text = selectedClass as String
```

**with**

```
newCardSetVC.strSelectedClass = selectedClass as String
```

**In `viewDidLoad:` of `NewCardSetViewController` put below line, it will display value onto your label.**

```
self.selectedClassLabel.text = self.strSelectedClass
```

you have created object, so all variable of `NewCardSetViewController` will get memory, but IBOutlet will not.

**IBOutlet will only get memory after segue perform or pushViewController.**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let classIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(classIndexPath)! as UITableViewCell
    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.labelText = "Just a Moment"
    if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {
        spinningActivity.hide(true)
        self.displayAlert("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing.")

    } else {
        spinningActivity.hide(true)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addCardSetSegue", sender: self)
    }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addCardSetSegue"{
        if let indexPath = tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath?{
             let selectedCell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
             let selectedClass = selectedCell.textLabel!.text!
             let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! NewCardSetViewController
             vc.selectedClassLabel.text = selectedClass as String
        }
    }
}
```

So when you `performSegueWithIdentifier` you are creating a instance if that VC and not using the instance you created in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. So the solution is to instead use the instance created by performSegue. Which is done by calling `segue.destinationViewController` in `prepareForSegue`.

An alternate solutions could be not calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` and instead calling something like `self.presentViewController(newCardSetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)` instead as I stated in the comments.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this ...

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segID" {

    let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
    let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! NewCardSetViewController
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathForSelectedRow)! as UITableViewCell
    let selectedClass = selectedCell.textLabel!.text!
    newCardSetVC.selectedClassLabel.text = selectedClass as String
        }
  }
```

and you can use
`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addCardSetSegue", sender: self)`

in your `didSelectRowAtindexPath`

if your `NewCardSetViewController` is not embedded in a nav controller you can skip one of the lines above and go straight to it with...

`let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! NewCardSetViewController`