# how to pass data when i click the tableviewcell in swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to send data from the tableview to the tableview of another `ViewController`. However, when pass the data, the data is converted to optional type.

So the SQL statement to be executed in another `ViewController` is not executed. An optional error occurred in `ViewDidLoad`.

I have also used the override prepare function, but the result is the same.
I can't understand why this is happening.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let itemCd = self.itemList[indexPath.row].itemCd
    let itemName = self.itemList[indexPath.row].itemName

    print(self.itemList[indexPath.row].itemCd)

    let infoVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HIST_RVC")
    if let _infoVC = infoVC as? HistviewController {

        _infoVC.itemCd = Int(itemCd)
        _infoVC.itemName = String(itemName)

        print(_infoVC.itemCd)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "moveHist", sender: self)
    }
```

When I print, I get the following result,

```
first : 1,
second : Optional(1)
```

other viewController:

```
class HistviewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var itemCd: Int!
var itemName: String!
// SQLite DB
var infomationDAO = infoDAO()
var infoList: [InfoVO]!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.infoList = self.infomationDAO.find(itemCd: self.itemCd)
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

sql find() function:

```
func find(itemCd: Int = 0) -> [InfoVO] {

    var infoList = [InfoVO]()

    do {
        // define condition
        let condition = itemCd == 0 ? "": "WHERE a.item_cd = \(itemCd)"

        let sql = """
        select a.info_cd, a.info_name, b.item_name
        from info_table a
        join item_table b
        on a.info_name = b.item_name
        \(condition)
        order by a.item_cd ASC
        """

        let rs = try self.fmdb.executeQuery(sql, values: nil)

        while rs.next() {
        ...}
```

Comment: `first : 1, second : Optional(1)`. Here `itemCd` -> `1 & Optional(1)` and `second` -> `first & second` ryt ?

Comment: @dinggu is your issue resolved?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers/9736559#9736559

Comment: _infoVC.itemName = String(describing:itemName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code your performing segue so you need to implement **func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)**   in your controller and pass the value.

**Code:**

```
 var selectedIndex = 0
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if let controller = segue.destination as? HistviewController {
                let itemCd = self.itemList[selectedIndex].itemCd
                let itemName = self.itemList[selectedIndex].itemName
                controller.itemcd = Int(itemcd)
                controller.itemName = String(itemName)
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In `HistviewController` declare `itemCd` and `itemName` as non-optional. There are only a very few cases where it's useful to declare *primitive* types like `String` and `Int` as optional.

   ```
   var itemCd = 0
   var itemName = ""
   ```
2. The `init?(String)` initializer return an optional because `"abc"` cannot be represented by an `Int`. Use the nil-coalescing operator to pass 0 if the initializer fails:

   ```
   _infoVC.itemCd = Int(itemCd) ?? 0
   ```

---

Note: In Swift avoid variable names with starting underscore character. That's very *objective-c-ish*. Write

```
if let infoVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HIST_RVC") as? HistviewController {
```